# Learning Python Exercise

Tags: python

I have taken it upon myself to learn python. As it is my second language is has not been that hard to get the hang of. I am looking for some simple python projects to undertake so I can better learn the syntax of the language in general. I would specifically like to learn the syntax of arrays, lists, and dictionaries.

---

Edit:
I cant say that one of your answers are right or wrong but between all of you i have alot of material! Thanks everyone :D

ps I particularly liked [Google's Python Class](http://code.google.com/edu/languages/google-python-class/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Google's Python class](http://code.google.com/edu/languages/google-python-class/) has a bunch of projects you can work on.

Answer (score 4):

[The Python Challenge](http://www.pythonchallenge.com/) has been by *far* the coolest exploratory stuff I've done with Python.

Take your time working through the problems - it's worth it.

Answer (score 2):

[Python Koans](http://bitbucket.org/gregmalcolm/python_koans/wiki/Home) is a good interactive tutorial that covers basic syntax and advanced concepts.

Answer (score 2):

Steve Lott's [Building Skills In Python](http://www.itmaybeahack.com/homepage/books/python.html) is great.  He's prominent on this site, too.

Answer (score 2):

A usual response to such things is [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net). Not necessarily special to python, but all those problems are solveable with python, and by working on them, you especially learn a lot of things that make Python special.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [pyschools.com](http://pyschools.com)
There are many small exercises categorized into different topics. Quite a fun way to learn how to program.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend the following e-book for learning Python. It covers several different programming paradigms and is a very good introduction to Python in general.

[www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/thinkCSpy.pdf](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/thinkCSpy.pdf)

If you are already familiar with programming in general then [Dive into Python](http://diveintopython.net/toc/index.html) is an unbeatable resource for getting the foundation of the language fast.

I have read both of the above and found them to be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Also something similar to Project Euler is Rosalind

http://rosalind.info/problems/list-view/

Most of the problems are solved by writing programs that perform opetarions on strings, which makes it a goot tool to learn about lists and dictionaries. And you also learn something about bioinformatics which doesn't really help you much in your programming career but is really cool =D

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to state the obvious, but why not read a good book or two, like:

[Learning Python: Powerful Object-Oriented Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596158068)

If you like more of a learn as you go approach, there's always the venerable:

[Python Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007973)

Answer (score 0):

Also in line with the Project Euler answer already provided, I'd recommend looking into some Code Kata.  I generally go through these as part of learning any new language, and here's a link to several good ones:

http://codingdojo.org/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?KataCatalogue

Also a Stack Overflow question discussing Kata:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44533/your-favorite-code-kata

Answer (score 0):

Python challenge is cool. And I see another good [http://projecteuler.net](http://projecteuler.net/problem=1)